# I wrote the code using the firebase dock(google cloud functions firebase auth), but it outputs an error, tell me what to do with it?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

There is a function for google cloud functions firebase. It is required to use the auth() module to authorize the user by email and password. I wrote the code using the firebase dock, but it outputs an error, tell me what to do with it?

```
exports.clientLogin = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const userLogin = await admin.auth().signInWithEmail({
    email: email,
    password: password,
  });
  const userId = userLogin.uid;
  res.json({ authId: userId });
});
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: the function just doesn't work. most likely something is wrong with the import

Comment: No no, what is the actual error text that is shown?